# How to execute a command against every file, replacing the contents of each file?

Tags: php, npm, gulp

Not interested in using a module for this.

I believe that to loop through all files in a folder, I can do this:

```
gulp.src(__dirname + '\\mysource\\**\\*.php', {read: false})
```

For every file found, I want to run a command, and save the contents on that file.
(`php -w FILE > FILE`)

My understanding is that I can do this with "spawn",

```
.pipe(spawn('php', ['-w'], ...))
```

But I'm not sure how I get the "current file", unless I do some kind of "forEach".

Comment: look at glob https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob for example `glob.sync` it returns an array of files found on which you can do a `forEach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general form using https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob `glob.sync` which returns an array.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const glob = require("glob");
const path = require("path");

// get an array of files
const files = glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'mysource\**\*.php');

gulp.task('default', function (done) {

  files.forEach(function (file) {

    return gulp.src(file, {read: false})

      // .pipe(do your stuff here)

      .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/" +  path.basename(file, '.php')));
  });
  done();
});
```